# How to insert an "apply" button in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I am building a job website and I am trying to insert an 'apply' button in a custom post-type single page (called 'vacancy') within WordPress.
I need this button to notify the admin of the new 'application' = meaning someone logged in clicked on the button.

I have thought about using the `comment_form()` function but I am not sure how to adapt it to register the "button" click. It doesn't show anything at all in fact.

I have got the following code inside the `WP_Query( $mypost )` `while( have_posts() ) : the_post();` loop:

```
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
    }
    comment_form( array(
        'comment_field' =>  '',
        'label_submit'  =>  __( 'Apply' ),
        'comment_notes_after'   => ''
    ),
    $mypost
    );
endif;
```

I don't want to affect the general comments as I may need them for the normal posts and pages, and preferably if I can separate it from the comments and instead have something else - but I can't think of another way to do it.

Thanks in advance! Really do appreciate any suggestions/help.

Comment: If you're not using comments, then don't use the comments function. The button is in a form? are you submitting anything with it?
The information you want to send to admin is by email?

Comment: Use a form plugin that sends to email and also to a database (like Gravity Forms). That's probably the most logical route.

Comment: Bruno, I was thinking whether I could integrate within the WordPress UI, and I thought the way comments work is the most similar way I know to what I wanted to do - send it to the admin dashboard area.
Thanks Aibrean, that's probably the best idea!..